# Foreach skip user by capability

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code:

```
foreach( get_users() as $user ) {

    // Set user ID
    $user_id = $user->data->ID; 

    // Only users who are contributors or above
    if (!user_can( $user_id, 'edit_posts' ) )
    return; 

    // Rest of code here

}
```

As you can see, I have set so that it only affects users who can `edit_posts`. But it is not working, can I not use `if (!user_can( $user_id, 'edit_posts' ) ) return;` within `foreach` or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you wish to only run the code if the `user_can` function returns a certain value.

You have two options here; the first, which is closer to what you have, uses the `continue` control structure:

```
foreach( get_users() as $user ) {

    // Set user ID
    $user_id = $user->data->ID; 

    // Only users who are contributors or above
    if (!user_can( $user_id, 'edit_posts' ) )
        continue; 

    // Rest of code here

}
```

However, lots of developers believe that if you need to use `continue` then you've probably got some poorly written code somewhere.  This is a matter of opinion, but personally I would opt for option 2, where you simply place the code you wish to run inside the `if` block:

```
foreach( get_users() as $user ) {

    // Set user ID
    $user_id = $user->data->ID; 

    // Only users who are contributors or above
    if ( user_can( $user_id, 'edit_posts' ) ){
        // Rest of code here
    }

}
```